# What is android.stamp in android-manifest?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apk, android-manifest

what does it mean in android-manifest?

```
<meta-data android:name="com.android.stamp.source" android:value="https://play.google.com/store" /> 
    <meta-data android:name="com.android.stamp.type" android:value="STAMP_TYPE_DISTRIBUTION_APK" />
```

Please explain me ,im a amateur programming 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SourceStamp improves traceability of apps with respect to unauthorized distribution.

> The stamp is part of the APK that is protected by the signing block.
> The APK contents hash is signed using the stamp key, and is saved as
> part of the signing block.